# Want to print last sentence

Tags: java

You must deliver exactly N kilograms of sugar to a candy store. The sugar made in the sugar factory is contained in a bag. The bag has 3 kg bag and 5 kg bag.
I try to carry as little bags as possible. For example, when you need to deliver 18 kilograms of sugar, you can take 6 bags of 3 kilograms, but if you deliver 3 kilograms and 3 kilograms, you can deliver a smaller number of bags.
Write a program to find out the number of bags you should take when you have to deliver exactly N kilograms of sugar.
(3<=N<=5000 AND If you can not make exactly N kilograms, print -1.)

---

In case of only 4 or 7 , it is not divided so I made it to print -1.
And to get the minimum bag, I used the code below.
But when I run this, the case if it is not divided by 5 or 3, the bottom sentence should be printed out but it is not working.
I want to know how does it works. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = input.nextInt();

    if (N % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println(N / 5);
    } else if (N == 4 || N == 7) {
        System.out.println(-1);

    } else
        for (int i = 1; (N - 3 * i) % 5 != 0; i++) {
            if ((N - 3 * i) % 5 == 0)
                System.out.println(i + (N - 3 * i) / 5);
            break;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: I made for loop to use minimum bags except for the case 4, 7, and  divided by 5 exactly.
to use the minimum basket I thought when we divide the weight(N) by 5 while continuing to take 3 kg from the weight N. The following condition and break were made to stop when the divisor of 3 was subtracted by 5 and then to output the number of bags.

Comment: If you're trying to minimize the total number of bags used, the answer you accepted is incorrect. Your logic is correct except for some small issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I read your comment now deleted. I understood what you saying. The reason why my code not runs was just my for loop was too complicated?

Comment: I think that's the only reason. If you update with my suggested change and still doesn't run, there might be another issue. But it should be correct then. However, the answer you accepted with many "else if"s is wrong if you want the least/smallest number of bags. (the reason being N/3 gives you a lot more bags than N/5)

Comment: Also you probably don't need 'break' if you change the for loop condition to "i < 5".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks there is a logic issue with your solution. Try the following :

```
boolean isPossible = true;

if (N % 5 == 0) {
    System.out.println("You need : " + (N / 5) + " bags");
} else {
    int diff = 0;
    for (int i = N; i > 0 && N >= 0; i--) {
        if (N % 5 != 0) {
            diff = N % 5;
            N = N - diff;
        } else {
            if (diff % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println("You need : " + (N / 5 + diff / 3) + " bags");
                isPossible = true;
                break;
            } else {
                N = N - 5;
                diff = diff + 5; 
            }
        }
    }
}

if (N <= 0 || !isPossible)
    System.out.println(-1);
```

Logic is explained below :

- Basically here we find the modulus of N with 5 and check if the
  remainder (in the example `diff`) is a multiple of 3.
- If the remainder (`diff`) is not a multiple of 3 then we reduce N by
  5 and increase `diff` by 5. This continues until we have found a match (`isPossible`) or else if not found `-1` is printed out.

Answer (score 1):

So as far as I understand, you're trying to use the smallest amount of 3kg bags in the last for loop and you want to break out as soon as the remainder is divisible by 5kgs.

```
(int i = 1; (N - 3 * i) % 5 != 0; i++)
```

Could you not have the middle part as i < 5?

```
(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
```

Also, you could get rid of the if condition
    if (N % 5 == 0) {

part by starting i at 0, so you account for the case N is divisible by 5:

```
(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = input.nextInt();

int sum = 0;
boolean isFound = false;

for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N / 2; j++) {
        if ((5 * i) + (3 * j) == N) {
            sum = i + j;
            isFound = true;
        }
    }
}

if (isFound ) {
    System.out.println("You require " + sum + " bags");
} else {
    System.out.println(-1);
}
```

Explanation:

The above code aims to find the possible combinations of the sum of the factors of 3 and 5 that give the number, i.e N:

For example: 
N = 32

For each iteration, the following condition is checked.
    `if((5 * i) + (3 * j) == N)`

The check continues until the smallest numbers that satisfy the condition are found.

> 5*0 + 3*0 = 0 which is not equal to 32
>
> 5*0 + 3*1 = 3 which is not equal to 32
>
> 5*0 + 3*2 = 6 which is not equal to 32

.
.

> 5*1 + 3*0 = 5 which is not equal to 32
>
> 5*1 + 3*1 = 8 which is not equal to 32
>
> 5*1 + 3*2 = 11 which is not equal to 32
>
> 5*1 + 3*4 = 17 which is not equal to 32

.
.

> 5*4 + 3*0 = 20 which is not equal to 32
>
> 5*4 + 3*1 = 23 which is not equal to 32
>
> 5*4 + 3*2 = 26 which is not equal to 32
>
> 5*4 + 3*3 = 29 which is not equal to 32
>
> 5*4 + 3*4 = 32

In this case, i=4 and j=4, i.e sum of bags required (i+j) = 8

isFound is set to true to indicate that the combination is found.

If no combination is found, isFound remains to be false, and -1 is printed.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. Function of N/2 in FOR loop is to roughly limiting the possible values of i and j??

Comment: Yes, because the number of bags that you need wouldn't exceed one half of the number you input. So limiting i, j to N/2 reduces the number of iterations you would have to go through.